# Remove parentheses around edition and add page numbers at the end in chicago style

Tags: bibtex, formatting, natbib, chicago-style

I'm not super familiar with modifying `.bst` files and my journal requires that there be no parentheses around editions and that page numbers appear at the end. Currently, a sample reference appears as follows:

> Doe, Jane 2009. "Editor's Note." In Victoria Allen (Ed.), *Gender Issues*, pp. 65-88. Routledge.

And I want it to appear as:

> Doe, Jane 2009. "Editor's Note." In Victoria Allen, ed., *Gender Issues*.  London: Routledge, 65-88.

I'm using a slightly modified version of `chicago style` and would like to know how to modify the `.bst` file further to incorporate these changes. A MWE is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[round,sectionbib,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,round,semicolon,aysep={},yysep={,}}

\begin{document}
* a lot of text *
\bibliographystyle{mychicago.bst}
\singlespacing
\bibliography{bib_sample}
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

In my `.bib` file, I have:

```
@incollection{sample2009,
author={Doe, Jane},
title={Editor's Note},
editor={Allen, Victoria}, 
booktitle={Gender Issues},
year={2009},
publisher={Routledge},
pages={65-88}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a few changes:

- To get rid of "pp.", modify the `format.pages` function to be:

  ```
  FUNCTION {format.pages}
  { pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages multi.page.check
      { pages n.dashify } % change this
      { pages } % change this
      if$
    }
    if$
  }
  ```
- To use "ed." instead of "(Ed.)", modify the `format.editor.fml` function to be:

  ```
  FUNCTION {format.editors.fml}
  { editor empty$
      { "" }
      { editor format.names.fml
        editor num.names$ #1 >
      { ", eds." * } % change this
      { ", ed." * } % change this
        if$
      }
    if$
  }
  ```

  You may also want to make similar changes to the `format.editors` function.
- To place the page numbers at the end, modify the `incollection` function to be:

  ```
  FUNCTION {incollection}
  { output.bibitem
    format.authors
    "author" output.check
    author format.key output
    output.year.check
    new.block
    format.title
    "title" output.check
    new.block
    crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle
      "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      address output
      publisher "publisher" output.check.colon
      format.chapter.pages output % move to after publisher
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref
      output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
    if$
    new.block
    note output
    fin.entry
  }
  ```

  You may need to make similar modifications to `inbook` and `inproceedings`.

I gather you've already modified `format.names` and `format.names.fml` to print full given names, not just initials, as well as adjusting things so that the title is quoted, so I haven't shown anything to do with these things.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{sample2009,
  author = {Doe, Jane},
  title = {Editor's Note},
  editor = {Allen, Victoria}, 
  booktitle = {Gender Issues},
  year = {2009},
  address = {London},
  publisher = {Routledge},
  pages = {65-88}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[round,sectionbib,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,round,semicolon,aysep={},yysep={,}}
\bibliographystyle{mychicago}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! And yes, I had already modified the code to print full first names and put the title in quotes. Super helpful!